# How to increase request feature speed?

Tags: geoserver, optimization

I use GeoServer with Oracle DB. The number of records in the database is fewer than 4000, but a feature request takes 5-6 seconds. How can I speed up this?

P.S. Native JAI is false in my GeoServer

**UPDATE:**

I have view which joins two tables. `int view sdo.geometry` is polygon with 12 points.

When I open it from layer preview it takes from 5 to 6 seconds.

**UPDATE 2**

I removed view and joins and it works great. I had to copy columns from one table to another for reading directly from table all fields. If someone knows solution when using views or joins please share :)

Comment: we need many more details on your set up to answer this. But probably you need to add indexes to your table.

Comment: I have already added indexes to my table. what else information you need? I'll post.

Thanks

Comment: what the data table looks like, what your query is? what is the exact SQL sent? what does explain say?

Comment: If you have identified the join as the problem you should analyze your query and indexes. What are you joining on? Are there any indexes used?

Comment: yes I use indexes, and join result table has less than 3200 rows.

Comment: But that still don't give a clue about what is happening. You have added indexes, yes, but are they used by the db? No one will be able to give a good answer here without knowing the exact query you are running and what query plan the db decides to use. In POstGIS you get that info from EXPLAIN query, I don't know what the syntax is in Oracle. Since it seems that it is your join that is the problem, I guess that you are using a spatial function in your join. Then it depends a lot of what function that is and in many cases how many vertex-points that your geoemtries contain.